# How to read from StorageFile until a character in found in Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have an app for Windows Store and what i am trying to do is read text from a file. I have two textFields. The descriptionTextField accepts new lines.

```
    // Read from file
    public async Task ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            // get the file
            StorageFile notesStorageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("NotesData.txt");
            var readThis = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(notesStorageFile);
            foreach (var line in readThis)
            {
                notesRepository.Add(new Note(line.Split(';')[0], line.Split(';')[1]));
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("File read successfully.");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error1: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Now if *NotesData.txt* has:

**Eggs;description eggs;**

it works file.

But if *NotesData.txt* has:

**Groceries;buy 10 eggs**

**buy 1 kg meat;**

I get the index out of bound error. I just cant figure out how to fix the ReadFile() code.

The exception appears when i am calling the method. The problem i believe is with the descriptionTextBox that can accept new lines.

NotesData.txt

Apples;description apples;         // works ok

Pears; description line 1

description line 2

description line 3;                    // problem

Pears; description line 1;         // works ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're trying to read back contents of a file you have previously saved and the problems you're having are just a consequence of the format you have selected for saving the data in the first place. Looking at it, new lines are not the only difficulty you're going to be having. What if the user decides to enter a semicolon in one of the textboxes? Are you preventing that?

I suggest you abandon your own serialization format and rather use one of the existing ones. If your `notesRespository` is a `List<Note>` this could be your (de)serialization code for XML:

```
private async Task Save(List<Note> notesRepository)
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<Note>));
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("notes.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, notesRepository);
    }
}

private async Task<List<Note>> Load()
{
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Note>));
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("notes.xml"))
    {
        return (List<Note>) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

And this for JSON:

```
private async Task Save(List<Note> notesRepository)
{
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (List<Note>));
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("notes.json", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    {
        jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, notesRepository);
    }
}

private async Task<List<Note>> Load()
{
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Note>));
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("notes.json"))
    {
        return (List<Note>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

When the repository gets too large to always load and save it as a whole you could even consider a structured storage like [SQLite](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems that the classic read/write from/to a text file that i learned this semester at university is limiting. Thanks for the bug with the ';'. I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
notesRepository.Add(new Note(line.Split(';')[0], line.Split(';')[1]));
```

assumes that you'll always have at least one semi-colon in a line. If you've got a line in your file which *doesn't* have that (e.g. a blank line) then it will fail.

It's not clear where that's where your problem is, because you haven't said where the exception's coming from, but that would be my first guess.

I'd also only do the split once:

```
string[] bits = line.Split(';');
if (bits.Length >= 2)
{
    // What do you want to do with lines with more than one semi-colon?
    notesRepository.Add(bits[0], bits[1]);
}
else
{
    // Handle lines without a semi-colon at all.
}
```